# Word Order Within the Satzklammer

Tags: sentence-structure

I am trying to write someothing close to the English:

```
The film begins with him writing a letter to her.
```

I have the sentence:

```
Der Film fängt mit Er ihn einen Brief schreiben an.
```

Is there a rule within the `mit Er ihn einen Brief schreiben` phrase [the Satzklammer?] that
forces `schreiben` to be at the end of the phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can also change the verb. Apart from modal verbs, there are some other verbs in German which allow for a construction similar to what you have in English, e.g. *sehen*:

> Zu Beginn des Films sieht man ihn ihr einen Brief schreiben.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as you've written it down is far from correct.

> Der Film fängt damit an, dass er ihm einen Brief schreibt.

That is the pretty much the only way. There is no German equivalent for the English.

> The film begins with his writing a letter to him.

The problem is the "his writing a letter". This phrasing does exist to an extend but since German uses a head-last principle you cannot add additional info.

> Der Film beginnt mit seinem Brief Schreiben... not nice but kind of okay
>
> Der Film beginnt mit seinem ihm einen Brief Schreiben... this is so out there that it's wrong.

Comment: As I see it, the OP wants "schreiben" at the end of what (s)he calls the Satzklammer. Not at the end of the sentence. But, I cannot complain, it's also not so transparent what is asked here. Every answer would  need speculation. Oder die Frage soll geschlossen werden: ich hab sowieso -1 in meiner Antwort.

Comment: Well, you're right. I'm speculating. Schreiben is at the end of what I perceive to be an attempted noun phrase and I do mention that in my answer. I am hesitant to vote close as I think OP ultimately tries to translate something directly that cannot be translated that way. I would have made this a comment but there are so many examples in it that I thought an answer would be more readable.

Comment: Entweder "Briefschreiben" (wie "Klavierspielen") oder wenn dir das nicht gefällt, dann zumindest "Brief-Schreiben". Im zweiten Satz dann in jedem Fall "Ihm-einen-Brief-Schreiben".

Comment: @Em1 wie wärs mit "das Brie frschreiben" ;).

Comment: @Emanuel The `Er` in the sentence is writing it to a `Sie` so that;s why I wrote ihn and not ihm. I understand that I am totally off, but how would I communicate the basic Idea " the film begins with him writing a letter to her."

Comment: `Der Film fängt damit an, dass er die Frauen einen Brief schreibt`?.

Comment: @Thalatta "Der Film fängt damit an, dass er *der Frau*  einen Brief schreibt"

Comment: @Thalatta... sorry for the confusion... I didn't pay too much attention to the gender :)

Answer (score 2):

One grammatical way to avoid a sentence composition with "dass" while still keeping the base skeleton "Der Film fängt mit ... an":

> Der Film fängt mit der Verfassung eines Briefes an sie durch ihn an.

Yet this is absolutely horrible style! 
In this case, it is not only the substantivation construct in the dative but the fact that "Verfassung" is a word that is most often used in the meaning "constitution" only. OTOH, "Schreibung" sounds even worse.

Like others say, a reformulation is unavoidable, and there are, of course plenty. One without "dass":

> Zu Beginn des Films schreibt er ihr einen Brief.

Comment: A few notes: a) +1 for avoiding "dass"!, b) it's probably helpful if you actually state clearly that `Verfassung` usually means `constitution`, c) the sentence is not in passive, it's is only substantivation (officially [nominalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) in english), d) you can avoid the very ugly "durch ihn" by using `mit seiner Verfassung eines Briefes an sie` (admittedly still bad style, but slightly better) or a somewhat poetic `Der Film beginnt mit dem Schreiben eines Briefs, von ihm an sie.`

Comment: Supplemental for d), you can completely avoid the nominalization by using a verbal style sentence like `Zu Beginn des Films schreibt er ihr einen Brief.` (or `einen Brief an sie`). This does of course change the focus of the sentence slightly, though the "beginning of the film" still remains in the exposition of the sentence.

Comment: @NevikRehnel Vielen Dank für die Anregungen, die ich, soweit es mir möglich war, in allergrößter Dankbarkeit, welche durch die nahenden Weihnachtstage, die stürmisch zu werden versprechen, nicht nur nicht getrübt, sondern eher angefacht wurde, eingearbeitet habe.

Comment: Es lebe der Satzeinschub!

Comment: Ja, wenn wir schon einmal bei Satzklammern sind, ein mir bis dato nicht geläufiges Wort, weshalb ich neim lesen des Titels zuerst dachte: Warum soll es in einer Salzkammer eine Wortordnung geben?"

Comment: Why not use "dem Verfassen" instead of "der Verfassung"? (Not that the sentence would lose much of its horribility)

Answer (score 0):

Wie die Frage, so die Antwort:

> Der Film fängt mit „Er [Modalverb] ihm einen Brief schreiben“ an.

is the only solution I see. Why?

- *einen Brief* is already the object in `Akkusativ`, so *ihn* is just wrong: I changed that into *ihm*.
- secondly, for *schreiben* to be at the end, you need a modal verb.

> Der Film fängt mit [dem Satz] „Er {muss·soll·will} ihm einen Brief schreiben“ an.

Comment: @NevikRehnel ach -1?, ich habe mal nur versucht, nett zum OP zu sein:)

Comment: Noch -2 sogar? Zumindest eine Erklärung?! :)

Comment: Ein Film fängt nicht mit einem Satz an. Direkte Rede an dieser Stelle impliziert ein Zitat. Das kann man bei einem Buch oder einer sonstigen textuellen Entität verwenden, aber doch nicht bei einem Film. Schließlich ist der Satz eine Beschreibung der Handlung und nicht der Ausschnitt eines Dialogs.

Comment: @flyx jetzt bin ich mir nicht sicher ob mein Argument gültig ist. Eher antwortete ich auf die Frage bevor, dass der OP das wieder editierte. Aber ich bin auch sicher, dass Filme mit einem Satz total anfangen können. Es kann doch der erste Bildschirm, der im Film erscheint, wie bei Lars von Triers Filmen "Prologue" oder "Chapter One: Grief" usw.

Comment: Okay, ja, wenn es wirklich ein Zitat ist, geht es. Aber eben nicht in diesem Fall, weil es eine Handlungsbeschreibung ist.

Comment: Dann aber sowas wie: "Zu Beginn des Filmes wird das Zitat <<...>> eingeblendet" oder iwas in der Art.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (somehow opposite to another answers, even mine): make a single sentence, without relative clauses.

Since

> *ein Mann, der einen Brief schreibt* ist *ein einen Brief schreibender Mann*

and

> *ein Brief, der einer Frau gewidmet wird* ist *ein einer Frau gewidmeter Brief*

the complete sentence would be:

> Der Film fängt mit einem einer Frau gewidmentem Brief schreibenden Mann an.

I don't know if the whole is grammatically OK (I actually expect corrections, firstly, for I don't know if *widmen* is the best possible verb). And I ask myself (if not here, I'll open a new question) if those sentences are actually readable.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I need to do some corrections. I changed *n* to *m* because *einem* relates to *Mann* and then *gewidmet* would be incorrectly inflected. Compare "auf einem grünen Rasen" but "einem auf grünem rasen liegenden mann".

Comment: Furthermore, you made the same mistake as Emanuel did. "Briefschreibend" must actually be one word: "fängt mit einem briefschreibenden Mann an". Look this way: "fängt mit einem schreibenden Mann an"->Inserting the noun "Brief" would make up an incorrect sentence. "fängt mit einem–Brief–schreibenden Mann an". You could interpret it as "fängt mit einem Brief an" but what is then "schreibenden Mann". Thus "briefschreibend" Problem: How to insert the adjective "einer Frau gewidmet" because you only want to modify "brief" not "briefscheibenden Mann". Well, frankly speaking: I do not know.

Comment: @em1 warte mal. Warum *gewidmetem* mit *m*? In "einem auf grünem Rasen liegenden Mann" haben wir ein *m* aufgrund der Präp. *auf*, richtig? Ich hatte *n* geschrieben weil man `widmet etw(A) jmdm`, oder? hier dieser *jemand* ist die Frau und dieser *etwas*, der Brief. Ich könnte auch eine neue Frage drüber stellen, damit die Diskusion nicht verloren geht.

Comment: OK. Die Sache ist ziemlich komplex hier. Ich war, bin und bleibe überzeugt davon, dass der Satz so definitiv falsch ist. Ich war überzeugt, dass das M richtig ist, war dann auf einmal der Meinung, dass es doch falsch ist, und jetzt denke ich wieder, es ist richtig. Der Satz ist ziemlich kompliziert. Ich muss mir da weiter Gedanken drüber machen... Meine Argumentation oben ist aber definitiv falsch.

Comment: @Em1... to put the confusion to rest: The sentence should be "Der Film fängt mit einem einen einer Frau gewidmeten Brief schreibenden Mann an." - here the parts mit einem Mann, Mann schreibt einen Brief, er schreibt einer Frau. It is a nice example for the twisted shit German grammar allows but it is not a version anyone would ever use :)