# Wie ist die korrekte Deklination eines Adjektivs und der korrekte Satzbau in einer komplex-verschachtelten Struktur?

Tags: sentence-structure, declension, hyphen

In einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/word-order-within-the-satzklammer/9050#9050) zu einer Frage hier, heißt es ursprünglich

> Der Film fängt mit einem einer Frau gewidmeten Brief schreibenden Mann an.

Ich habe spontan die Deklination von *gewidmet* geändert und aus dem *N* ein *M* gemacht. Über meine Argumentation bin ich nicht mehr ganz schlüssig, aber ich versuche mal meine inzwischen verwirrten Gedankengänge niederzuschreiben.

> Der Film fängt mit einem Mann an. - *Mit wem? Mit einem Mann.*)

Soweit nichts auszusetzen. Erstes Problem nun:

> Der Film fängt mit einem Brief schreibenden Mann an. - *Grammatisch OK, aber problematisch.*

Warum? Kurz ein anderes Beispiel: Man *spielt Klavier*. Man kann dann *gut [Klavier spielen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Verb.html#Anchor-Verbindungen-14210)*. Und man kann *Klavier spielend(=einfach) lernen*. Aber spielt man gerade Klavier, ist man *[klavierspielend oder Klavier spielend](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Adjektiv.html#Anchor-Verbindungen-35882)*. Und das Spielen des Klaviers ist [das Klavierspielen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Nomen.html#Anchor-11481). Also "der Klavier spielende(=klavierspielende) Klavierspieler lernt beim Klavierspielen das Klavier spielend einfach spielen".
Daraus folgt, schreibt man einen Brief ist man entweder *briefschreibend* oder *Brief schreibend*. Der Satz ist deswegen problematisch weil ich dazu verleitet werde, zu glauben, dass der Brief das eigentliche Dativobjekt ist.

> Der Film fängt mit einem Brief an. - *Mit wem? Mit einem Brief.*

Würde der Satz das Adjektiv *briefschreibend* enthalten, wäre es sofort einleuchtend.

Bei meiner ursprünglichen Korrektur war ich noch davon ausgegangen, dass es *briefschreibend* sein muss und nicht *Brief schreibend*. Diese Erkenntnis macht es aber nur umso komplizierter, weil ab hier müssen wir also zwei Wege verfolgen.

Erstmal möchte ich hier einen kurzen Ausflug zur Zeichensetzung machen. Was bewirkt ein Komma, was passiert, wenn es wegfällt:

> *Ein gutes neues Jahr* versus *Ein gutes, neues Jahr*

Setzt man ein Komma, so sind die Adjektive gleichrangig. Sie ergänzen sich. Man kann das Komma durch *und* ersetzen und es wird deutlich: Das Jahr ist also gut und neu.

> Ein gutes und neues Jahr

Setzt man kein Komma, bildet das zweite Adjektiv zusammen mit dem Nomen eine feste Bindung, welche durch das erste Adjektiv modifziert wird. Folglich ist das neue Jahr gut.

> Ein gutes Neues Jahr

Wofür das Ganze? Ich möchte zeigen, dass wir in dem Ausgangssatz so oder so in ein Problem rennen:

> Ein gewidmeter, Brief schreibender Mann
>   Ein gewidmeter, briefschreibender Mann
>   Ein gewidmeter und Brief schreibender Mann
>   Ein gewidmeter und briefschreibender Mann
>   Ein gewidmeter Brief schreibender Mann
>   Ein gewidmeter briefschreibender Mann

In jedem dieser Sätze ist der Mann gewidmet. So oder so. Der Unterschied: Entweder ist er **außerdem** briefschreibend oder er ist eben **der** briefschreibende Mann.

Daraus ergibt sich das der folgende Satz in jeglicher Konstellation eine falsche Aussage vermittelt und es liegt **nicht** an der Kommasetzung:

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten(,) Brief schreibenden Mann an.
>   Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten(,) briefschreibenden Mann an

Einzige Lösung die wir haben, ist der Einsatz von Hyphen. Und hier bin ich mit meinem Latein zu Ende. Wie wird der Satz korrekt aufgebaut, so dass nicht der Mann, sondern der Brief gewidmet ist, und der Mann weiterhin briefschreibend ist. Ab hier ist es wichtig, dass meine ursprüngliche Annahme, dass es *briefschreibend* sein muss, falsch ist.

> (a) Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten-Brief schreibenden Mann an.

Ich glaube, bin mir aber hier absolut unsicher, dass dies richtig ist. Nebenfrage 1: Stimmt das?
Falsch wäre meiner Meinung aber:

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten-Briefschreibenden Mann an.

Nebenfrage 2: Stimmt das?
Hauptfrage 1: Wie kann ich ein Nomen, welches mit einem anderen Wort verschmolzen ist, und zum Adjektiv wurde, wiederum mit einem Adjektiv so modifizieren, dass dadurch *nicht* das gesamte Adjektiv oder das davon referenzierte Nomen verändert wird?

Eine Überlegung, die ich habe, ist, ob hier eine Trennung mit zwei Hyphen notwendig ist, so wie in "[das Drachen-steigen-Lassen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Bindestrich/Wortgruppen.html#Anchor-Als-23240)". Leider passt die Regel nicht ganz auf das Problem hier, weil es dort um Nomen geht, nicht um Adjektive. Frage 3 also, ist

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten-Brief-schreibenden Mann an.

grammatisch richtig und bedeutet er, dass der Brief, der den Mann schreibt, gewidmet ist.

Als hätte ich nicht schon längst Kopfschmerzen, fehlt jetzt aber noch die Information, **wem** denn der Brief gewidmet ist. Und an der Stelle kommt dann auch das *M* ins Rennen.

Ich gehe im folgenden davon aus, dass der oben mit (a) gekennzeichnete Satz korrekt ist. Da mir nicht klar ist, wie der Satz korrekt lautet, wenn das Nomen in einem aus einem Wort bestehenden Adjektiv verschmolzen ist, gehe ich darauf vorerst nicht mehr ein.

Vorneweg: Ich habe null Ahnung, wie der Satz überhaupt korrekt zu schreiben wäre. Ich maches mir einfach und setze durchgehend Hyphen.

> Der Film fängt mit einem einer-Frau-gewidmeten-Brief schreibenden Mann an.
>   Der Film fängt mit einem einer-Frau-gewidmetem-Brief schreibenden Mann an.

Zu untersuchen ist an dieser Stelle, ob ein *N* oder ein *M* zu setzen ist.

> Nominativ: Ein gewidmeter Brief kam heute mit der Post.
>   Nominativ: Ein einer Frau gewidmeter Brief kam heute mit der Post.
>   Akkusativ: Ich sende dir einen gewidmeten Brief.
>   Akkusativ: Ich sende dir einen einer Frau gewidmeten Brief.
>   Dativ: Ich sorge mit einem gewidmeten Brief für Unruhe
>   Dativ: Ich sorge mit einem einer Frau gewidmete? Brief für Unruhe.

Im Nominativ und Akkusativ besteht überhaupt kein Problem, weil in sowieso eine Übereinstimmung der Endung des Artikels und des Adjektivs vorliegt. Im Dativ ist dies nicht so. Und mein Gefühl sagt mir, dass die "Wem-gewidmet?"-Information hier eine solche Gewichtung hat, dass eine Anpassung von *N* zu *M* notwendig ist.
Hauptfrage 2: Liege ich mit meinem Gefühl richtig oder wie muss hier korrekt dekliniert werden?

Und die Masterfrage: Wie lauten die zwei korrekten Formen (siehe *Brief schreibend* und *briefschreibend*) für den vollständigen Satz? Wo sind jeweils Hyphen zu setzen? Ist es überhaupt möglich, den Satz in dieser Form korrekt und eindeutig zu gestalten?

---

Anmerkung: Für Hauptfrage 2 kann man auch von diesem "vereinfachten" Satz ausgehen:

> Der Film fängt mit einem einer Frau gewidmete? Brief an.

Comment: PS: Ich hätte gerne einen Hut für "die längste Frage der Welt". Und Hut ab für all diejenigen, die diese Frage zu Ende lesen (und verstehen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Nebenfrage 1**

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten-Brief schreibenden Mann an.

ist orthografisch falsch. Adjektiv-Substantiv-Gruppen werden nie mit Bindestrichen versehen (im Gegensatz zum Englischen).

**Nebenfrage 2**
Erübrigt sich mit der Antwort auf Nebenfrage 1, wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe.

**Hauptfrage 1**

> Wie kann ich ein Nomen, welches mit einem anderen Wort verschmolzen ist, und zum Adjektiv wurde, wiederum mit einem Adjektiv so modifizieren, dass dadurch *nicht* das gesamte Adjektiv oder das davon referenzierte Nomen verändert wird?

Gar nicht. Dass das Nomen mit einem Adjektiv versehen werden kann, ist sogar ein Hauptkriterium dafür, dass keine Verschmelzung vorliegt und die Kombination nicht zusammengeschrieben wird (siehe insbesondere die Beispiele zu § 36 (2.1) der Rechtschreibregeln). Ein anderes Beispiel: *gebratene Würstchenbude* bedeutet immer, dass die Bude selbst gebraten ist (was unsinnig ist) – und das wird mit Zeichensetzung auch nicht besser. Sollen die Würstchen gebraten sein, muss z. B. von einer *Bude für gebratene Würstchen* oder einer *Bratwurst-Bude* gesprochen werden.

**Frage 3**

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmeten-Brief-schreibenden Mann an.

ist nicht richtig. Der Satz kann aber durch einen Artikel verständlich und richtig gemacht werden:

> Der Film fängt mit einem einen gewidmeten Brief schreibenden Mann an.

oder durch einen Plural:

> Der Film fängt mit einem gewidmete Briefe schreibenden Mann an.

**Hauptfrage 2 und Masterfrage**
Dem Satz fehlt auf jeden Fall ein Artikel:

> Der Film fängt mit einem einen einer Frau gewidmeten Brief schreibenden Mann an.

Dieser Satz ist so korrekt – wenn auch furchtbar hässlich.

Zur Verdeutlichung nochmal anders:

```
Der Film fängt                                                               an.
               mit einem                                                Mann
                                                           schreibenden
                         einen                       Brief
                                          gewidmeten
                               einer Frau
```

Eine korrekte Form mit *briefschreibend* gibt es nicht, s. o.

Comment: Ich bin immer so voreilig. Also auf den ersten Blick. Ja richtig. Aber dann "auf einem grüneN Rasen", aber "auf grüneM Rasen". Ich denke auch hier ist es möglich, den Artikel fallen zu lassen und dann wird aus dem N ein M. "Der Film fängt mit einem einer Frau gewidmeteM Brief schreibenden Mann an." Gewidmet bezieht sich ja nachwievor auf die Frau, also Wem?

Comment: Em1: Wenn aber *gewidmet* sich auf *die Frau* bezieht  (was wir eigentlich, vermute ich, beide denken), woher kommt denn die (Dativ-)Endung *m*? Gibt es keinen `Dativ` mehr vorhanden. Der`Dativ` der Präp *mit* und *einem* sind ein Paar. Dann *einer Frau* und *widmen* ein anderes. Woher würde denn das "m"  kommen? –

Comment: @Em1... theoretisch hast du Recht, aber in der Praxis ist das so verschwurbelt und kaum prozessierbar... bilde einfach mal den Nominativ :"Frau gewidmeter Brief liegt auf dem Tisch."... das kingt schon sehr fragwürdig. "Frau gewidmeten Brief schreibe ich." das ist noch komischer. Das Problem ist, denke ich, dass es für Brief und widmen NIE funktioniert, den Artikel wegzulassen. Es klingt immer schlecht und hier noch schlechter. Generell ist ein "Doppelnomen" ohne Artikel immer brrrr "Gutem Wein zugeneigten Mannes Frau trinkt gern mal einen mit." ... hmmm

Answer (score 7):

Wenn man die Häufung unbestimmter Artikel vermeiden will, die bei **a)**

```
Der Film fängt                                                               an.
               mit einem                                                Mann
                                                           schreibenden
                         einen                       Brief
                                          gewidmeten
                               einer Frau
```

auftritt, bleiben die Varianten **b)**

```
Der Film fängt                                                          an.
               mit                                                 Mann
                                                      schreibendeM
                   einen                       Brief
                                    gewidmeten
                         einer Frau
```

und **c)**

```
Der Film fängt                                                         an.
               mit einem                                          Mann
                                                     schreibenden
                                               Brief
                                    gewidmeten
                         einer Frau
```

oder gar **d)**

```
Der Film fängt                                                   an.
               mit                                          Mann
                                               schreibendem
                                         Brief
                              gewidmeten
                   einer Frau
```

und auf die Spitze getrieben

```
Der Film fängt                                             an.
               mit                                    Mann
                                         schreibendem
                                   Brief
                        gewidmeten
                   Frau
```

Aber diese Varianten scheitern alle daran, dass die zählbaren Substantive Mann/Brief/Frau dringend des Artikels bedürfen. Ohne diesen klingt solch ein Satz *bestenfalls* nach einer überkürzten Zeitungsschlagzeile ("Mann beißt Hund") oder als typischer Fehler von Fremdsprachlern, deren Muttersprache auf Artikel verzichtet (z.B. Russisch).
Nota bene, es kommt auf die Zählbarkeit an und hat nichts mit der Verschachtelung zu tun: "Der Film fing mit großem Mann an" ginge auch nicht, wohl aber "Der Film fing mit großem Radau an."

Comment: Grammatikalisch korrekt? Vielleicht! Aber ganz sicher stilistisch sehr fragwürdig! Für eine Verbesserung bräuchte ich mehr Kontext. Ich erfinde mal etwas: «Der Film fängt damit an, dass Oskar einen Brief schreibt. Dieser Brief ist seiner Frau gewidmet.» Grammatikalisch korrekte aber unverständlich verschachtelte Formen sind für mich ein Missbrauch der Sprache.

Comment: @nalply Das ist sehr richtig bemerkt, aber die OP-Frage zielte ja genau auf die (in der Tat fragwürdige bis übertriebene, auf jeden Fall in diesem Ausmaß gewiss nicht gerade sehr verständliche) Situation der verschachtelten Formulierung ab

Comment: Darum auch nur ein Kommentar, weil mein Beitrag die Frage nicht beantwortet. ;-)