# Korrekter Kasus in "auf brutale Verbrechen fixierte/fixierter/fixierten Gang"

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective-ending

Wir sind uns uneinig.
Welche Variante des folgende Satzes ist korrekt, und weshalb?

> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer in London auf brutale Verbrechen **fixierte** Gang.
>
> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer in London auf brutale Verbrechen **fixierter** Gang.
>
> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer in London auf brutale Verbrechen **fixierten** Gang.

Comment: Unabhängig von der eigentlichen Frage finde ich *in London* unglücklich platziert, da es der Gang egal ist, wo sie brutale Verbrechen begeht (und sie, wenn ich den Film richtig rate, auch Verbrechen außerhalb Londons begehen).

Comment: Ich finde die Platzierung auch unglücklich, aber sie ist nicht wirklich falsch. Deutsch ist eine Sprache, die solche Freiheiten in der Wortstellung erlaubt.

Comment: Die Satzstellung finde ich auch unbedenklich, auch wenn "in London" den Abschluss des Satzes bilden könnte. Solange es nicht unmittelbar hinter "Verbrechen" steht.

Answer (score 10):

Ich habe mal eine ähnliche Frage gestellt und [diese Antwort von Wrzlprmft](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9051/wie-ist-die-korrekte-deklination-eines-adjektivs-und-der-korrekte-satzbau-in-ein/9052#9052) hilft dabei, auch diese Frage hier zu beantworten.

Wenn man den Satz mal etwas grafisch aufbereitet, sieht es wie folgt aus:

```
Der Film erzählt die Geschichte
                                einer                                  Gang.
                                                             fixierten
                                      auf brutale Verbrechen
```

Ich habe hier "in London" mal der Einfachheit halber wegfallen lassen.

Letzten Endes sieht man, dass hier der Genitiv von *fixiert* (gemischte Flexion: [einer fixierten](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/fixiert:A)) notwendig ist. Die Frage in der Schule würde lauten: "Wessen Geschichte erzählt der Film? Die Geschichte einer ... fixierten Gang."

Comment: Schöne Darstellung! +1

Answer (score 5):

Richtig ist:

> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer in London auf brutale Verbrechen **fixierten** Gang.

Mach es dir einfacher, indem du das komplizierte Attribut »in London auf brutale Verbrechen fixiert??« durch ein einzelnes Wort ersetzt:

> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer **aktiv??** Gang.

Jetzt ist klar, dass das Objekt im Genitiv steht (»Wessen Geschichte wird erzählt?« - »Die Geschichte einer Gang«)

Da die Gang im Genitiv steht, muss auch ihr Attribut im selben Fall stehen. Der Film erzählt also ...

> die Geschichte einer **aktiven** Gang.

oder eben

> die Geschichte einer **fixierten** Gang.

Nun muss man nur noch hinzufügen, worauf die Gang fixiert ist, nämlich »auf brutale Verbrechen«:

> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer **auf brutale Verbrechen fixierten** Gang.

Und man kann hinzufügen, wo diese Fixierung stattfindet, nämlich »in London«. Da gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten:

> Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer **auf brutale Verbrechen in London fixierten** Gang.
>   Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer **in London auf brutale Verbrechen fixierten** Gang.

Comment: Oder "einer auf brutale Verbrechen fixierten Gang in London".

Comment: @userunknown: Das bedeutet aber etwas anderes. »Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer in London auf Verbrechen fixierten Gang« heißt, dass die Gang in London auf Verbrechen fixiert ist, und der Film die Geschichte dieser Gang erzählt. Im Film kann daher ein Teil der Handlung auch in Paris spielen, wo die Gang nicht auf Verbrechen fixiert ist, sondern irgend etwas harmloses macht. »Der Film erzählt die Geschichte einer auf Verbrechen fixierten Gang in London« heißt, dass die Gang generell auf Verbrechen fixiert ist (u.a. auch in Paris), der Film erzählt aber nur von den Ereignissen in London.

Comment: Ja, eine Gang die in London zuschlägt und die Beute in Paris verjuxt, und beides nimmt ca. 50% des Films ein - da wäre meine Alternative schlecht.